# How to calculate number of digits of a large number?

Tags: calculus, logarithms

Does anyone know any efficient ways of finding the number of digits in the large number $N = 4^{4^{4^4}}$? Thanks.

Comment: The number of digits of a natural number $N$ expressed in base $10$ is $\lfloor\log_{10}(N)\rfloor+1$. I am not sure how one would go about computing this in an effective way.

Answer (score 3):

This is a really interesting topic! I googled around a bit and discovered a question which somebody else asked, which looks similar to yours. And below it is an excellent answer.
[Finding the number of digits of a large number.](http://mathcentral.uregina.ca/qq/database/qq.09.96/leung1.html)

I hope this helps.

Seraphina

Answer (score 3):

An approximation: $4^{4^4} = 4^{256}$ is approximately $1.34078079 \times 10^{154}$

So the number of digits in $4^{4^{4^4}}$ is approximately $\log_{10}4\times1.34078079 \times 10^{154}$ which is about $8.0723047\times10^{153}$.

It would not be too arduous to (get a computer to) perform this calculation exactly.

**Update**
The number of digits required is $\lfloor 4^{256}\times \log_{10}4 \rfloor + 1 = \lfloor 2^{513}\times \log_{10}2 \rfloor + 1$. If $\log_{10}2$ is calculated in binary, the multiplication by $2^{513}$ is just a matter of shifting bits, and the problem is reduced to calculating $\log_{10}2$ with the necessary accuracy, which admittedly is not simple.
For completeness, here is the [entire WolframAlpha calculation](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=floor%284%5E256+%2a+log10%284%29%29%2B1).

Comment: See mr. FS's answer below. One of you is really off track..

Comment: @nbubis: see my comment under mr.FS's answer.

Comment: I'm sorry about that, you are right. This is because exponentiation is right-associative, right?

Comment: Are you suggesting that it would not be too arduous to express $4^{4^{4^4}}$ explicitly in base 10? If not, what are you proposing?

Comment: @TonyK, I'm saying that it wouldn't be too hard to perform the full  $\log_{10}4×1.34078079×10^{154}$ calculation, but accurately.

Comment: You mean the full $\log_{10}4 \times 4^{256}$ calculation, presumably. For me, that would be an arduous computation.

Answer (score 0):

The exact number of digits is

```
? ceil(4^4^4*log(4)/log(10))
%39 = 80723047260282253793826303970853990300713679217387430318670828284184144815
68309149198911814701229483451981557574771156496457238535299087481244990261351117
```

The number of digits has itself $154$ digits.